# Apply Database Changes after edit SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DataBase SQL , I did some changes in tables and datatype of this data base 
but this data base contains data

I used a select Insert statement from the old database to the new one after edit

Is it the best way to bring he data to the new database or I can use better way ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends why you are doing it and when.

If you are doing this as a one off process on your development machine and there is only a small number of simple tables then this approach will be fine

If you are doing it for a larger number of tables, need it to be re-runnable or want a GUI then use SSIS or ["SQL Server Import and Export Wizard"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). It's easy to use.